# Error en LOAD DATA LOCAL de MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy usando `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, para llenar una tabla y para probarlo uso un texto como este:

```
kffokwofkwf  "hostname"
ksakosak "IP" kdosko
_ "mac_eth"____
______ "mac_wifi"_
```

El cual tengo en mi tabla 5 campos:

```
(ID AUTOINCREMENT, HOSTNAME,IP.MAC_ETH_,MAC WIFI)
```

Al hacer el `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, me guarda todo en los diferentes campos, es decir, que parece que no reconozca el `ENCLOSED BY '"'`

¿Alguien que me pueda guiar?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
load data local infile '/listado1.txt'
into table computadora 
FIELDS  ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY '\n'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  (HOSTNAME,IP,mac_eth,mac_wifi) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que noto es que tu delimitador de campos es el mismo que tu delimitador de registros...

En tu caso el algoritmo, en la primera línea encontrará el delimitador de registro y concluye que hay datos insuficientes para llenar la fila de la tabla en la base de datos.

Answer (score -1):

En vez de poner:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  (HOSTNAME,IP,mac_eth,mac_wifi) ;
```

Prueba con:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
            (HOSTNAME, IP, mac_eth, mac_wifi);
```

Y quita

```
FIELDS  ENCLOSED BY '"'  ESTO => (TERMINATED BY '\n')
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Tal como está tu propuesta, se parece más a un comentario porque sugiere hacer una prueba. Dada la antiguedad de la pregunta, sería mucho más útil una respuesta concreta en lugar de una que parece estar esperando una confirmación a ver si la prueba sugerida funcionó.